# How to get focus back on transparent (ClickThrough enabeled) Window

Tags: c++, c, winapi, alpha-transparency, click-through

I am working on an application in which a window is transparent initially,then on a key press (say `shift+tab`) window should be **Not** `ClickThrough`. Code which I use to get `ClickThrough` is as follow:

```
_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, 
            TEXT("Example"), 
            title, WS_BORDER,
            GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) / 2 - _width / 2,
            GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) / 2 - _height / 2,
            _width, _height,
            NULL, NULL,
            NULL, NULL);
int opacity = 70;
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(_hwnd, 0, (255 * opacity) / 100, LWA_ALPHA);
```

Now, any solution to get **Not** `ClickThrough`? I google it but never find any one.

Comment: Waht are you calling "Not ClickThrough"?

Comment: Is it C, or C++?

Comment: C or C++ does not matter here

Comment: Hmm, that is not a transparent window.  There is already a decent alternative for a window that is transparent, click-through and can't be focused by clicking: don't create it.  Use RegisterHotKey() to recognize the keystroke.

Comment: Is it possible to get focus to the window or not .. ?

Comment: Focus is controlled per thread. But that doesn't buy you much. You're probably interested in foreground activation instead. [Foreground activation permission is like love: You can’t steal it, it has to be given to you](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090220-00/?p=19083). If you registered a hotkey, then [Pressing a registered hotkey gives you the foreground activation love](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090226-00/?p=19013), but we don't know any of that.

Comment: it was possible .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I have done this using registering **HotKeys**: **WndProc** is as follows:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    //break;
    case WM_HOTKEY:
    {
        switch (wparam)
        {
        case 1:// Close Window
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        case 2://Disable ClickThrough
            SetWindowLong(hwnd, -20, WS_EX_LAYERED); //-16 for window style
            break;
        case 3://enable ClickThrough
            SetWindowLong(hwnd, -20, WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT); 
            break;
        }
    }
    break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
    {
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        return 0;
    }
    break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wparam, lparam);
    }


}
```

Register **HotKeys** as follows:

```
RegisterHotKey(_hwnd, 1, MOD_SHIFT, 0x43); //shift + c
RegisterHotKey(_hwnd, 2, MOD_SHIFT, 0x44); //shift + d
RegisterHotKey(_hwnd, 3, MOD_SHIFT, 0x45); //shift + e
```